# How to use indexOf and lastIndexOf?

Tags: java

I have an HTML source code in one `String`. I want to get a part of string using `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`, but I only get `int`eger

```
textView.setText("");
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
// Get the response

ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String response_str = client.execute(request, responseHandler);

//response_str.lastIndexOf("morning—the sixth day.");
textView.setText( response_str.indexOf("<div class='commentary-link'>"););
```

I want to get a part of HTML code, and don't know how to do that.

thanks all

Comment: are you looking for string's `substring` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`indexOf`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) returns an int, which represents the last index of the substring in the whole string. Use this index to with [`String#substring()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) get a sub-string of the original:

```
int index =  response_str.indexOf("<div class='commentary-link'>");
textView.setText( response_str.substring(index));
```

The use of `lastIndexOf` is pretty much the same:

```
int index =  response_str.lastIndexOf("<div class='commentary-link'>");
textView.setText( response_str.substring(index));
```

Comment: i have indexOf but how to set lastIndexOf??